# paso de cadena por referencia en C

Tags: c, string, paso-por-referencia

Tengo este código para invertir el orden de una cadena sin embargo, **tengo el problema de poder imprimirlo en el resultado en el main pasando el string por valor (return)** pero no he logrado hacerlo, aunque si imprimo la cadena dentro de la función el algoritmo está correcto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char function(char cadena[]);

int main()
{
    char string[10], cadena[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d'};

    printf("\ncadena invertida: %s", function(cadena));

    return 0;
}

char function(char cadena[] )
{
    char cadenainterna[10];
    int cont = 0;
    
    for(int i=9; i>=0; i--)
    {
        cadenainterna[cont]=cadena[i];
        cont++;
    }
    
    return cadenainterna;
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el error que te da?

Answer (score 2):

cadena es un array:

```
char cadena[] = {'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d'};
```

Que, por cierto, sería recomendable dejarlo así:

```
char cadena[] = "HelloWorld";
```

Por dos motivos:

- Legibilidad
- La cadena con comillas dobles añade automáticamente el finalizador de cadena `\0`

El caso, `cadena` hemos dicho que es un array, es decir, C lo va a tratar como si fuese un puntero. ¿Qué implica esto? Que si tu modificas `cadena` desde `funcion`, los cambios se reflejarán también en el `main`:

```
void function(char * cadena)
{
    int length = strlen(cadena);
    for(int i=length-1, cont=0; i>cont; i--, cont++)
    {
        char c = cadena[i];
        cadena[i] = cadena[cont];
        cadena[cont] = c;
    }
}
```

Si quisieses generar una cadena nueva en vez de sobreescribir, tienes dos opciones:

- Haces que la función reciba dos parámetros, la cadena origen y la destino
- Usas memoria dinámica para crear espacio para la nueva cadena y usas `return`

Si optas por usar dos parámetros, tienes que tener en cuenta que aquí te toca finalizar la cadena. Si no haces esto no podrás usar las funciones propias de C para manipular/mostrar la cadena:

```
void function(char const* origen, char * destino)
{
    int length = strlen(origen);
    for(int i=length-1, cont=0; i>=0; i--, cont++)
    {
        destino[cont] = origen[i];
    }

    destino[length] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char cadena[] = "HelloWorld";
    char destino[20];
    
    function(cadena, destino);
    puts(destino);
}
```

Usar memoria dinámica tiene como requisito liberar dicha memoria cuando ya no es necesaria.

Nota que en este caso `function` devuelve un elemento de tipo `char*`, no `char` como era tu caso:

```
char* function(char const* cadena)
{
    int length = strlen(cadena);
    char * destino = (char*)malloc(length * sizeof(char));
    for(int i=length-1, cont=0; i>=0; i--, cont++)
    {
        destino[cont] = cadena[i];
    }

    destino[length] = '\0';
    return destino;
}

int main()
{
    char cadena[] = "HelloWorld";
    
    char * destino = function(cadena);
    puts(destino);
    free(destino);
}
```

¿Y no se puede declarar un array en `function` y devolverlo?

Pues lo cierto es que no, las variables declaradas dentro de `function` son variables locales y su vida queda limitada a dicha función. Fuera de esa función, el contenido del array no sería válido, pues esa región de memoria podrá ser utilizada por otras variables de tu aplicación.

Además, fíjate que el compilador no te deja devolver un elemento de tipo `char[]`:

```
prog.c:5:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token
    5 | char[] function(char const* cadena)
      |     ^
```

Sin embargo si podrías devolver un `char*` ... pero eso sería devolver un puntero que apuntaría a la región de memoria donde estaría tu array local. Aquí se produciría el error que te he comentado antes. El puntero, una vez abandonada la función, estaría direccionando memoria que ya no está siendo utilizada por el array, que ya no existe al estar fuera de ámbito.